# How do I mount a ConfigMap volume for VMWare's fluentd operator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, fluentd, amazon-eks

I am trying to mount a Kubernetes `configmap` for VMWare's Fluentd operator [[1](https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator)]. I've checked the documentation and the helm chart indicates that you have to specify an additional volume as a parameter called `fluentd.extraVolumeMounts`

The helm chart I'm using to install the operator is below :

```
#!/bin/sh
# helmenv set to helm3

CHART_URL='https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator/releases/download/v1.12.0/log-router-0.3.3.tgz'

# Set environment variables.
REGION='us-east-1'
CLUSTER='dev'
ENV='dev'
IMAGE_TAG='v1.12.0'

VOLUME_MOUNT="
- name: fluentd-es-templates
  mountPath: /templates"

EXTRA_VOLUME="
- name: fluentd-es-templates
  configMap:
    name: fluentd-es-templates"

# Install the fluentd operator in kube-system.
# helm install kfo ${CHART_URL} \
helm upgrade --install kfo ${CHART_URL} \
  --set meta.key=metadata \
  --set meta.values.region=${REGION} \
  --set meta.values.env=${ENV} \
  --set meta.values.cluster=${CLUSTER} \
  --set rbac.create=true \
  --set image.tag=${IMAGE_TAG} \
  --set image.repository=vmware/kube-fluentd-operator \
# --set fluentd.extraVolumeMounts=[$EXTRA_VOLUME]
# --set extraVolumes=[${EXTRA_VOLUME}]
```

When I un-comment the lines that set the volumes, the helm script fails. My question is, how do I populate the `VOLUME_MOUNT` and `EXTRA_VOLUME` variables with the correct json or yaml?
I'm trying to do everything in one file and don't want to split things into multiple files.

Comment: Are you restricted to sh or can you use bash?

Comment: @jordanm bash is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use a values file from within the shell script via process substitution. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CHART_URL='https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator/releases/download/v1.12.0/log-router-0.3.3.tgz'

read -r -d '' values << EOF
meta:
  key: metadata
  values:
    region: "us-east-1"
    env: "dev"
    cluster: "dev"
rbac:
  create: true
image:
  repository: vmware/kube-fluentd-operator
  tag: "v1.12.0"
fluentd:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: fluentd-es-templates
      mountPath: /fluentd/etc/mappings
extraVolumes:
  - name: fluentd-es-templates
    configMap:
      name: fluentd-es-templates
EOF

helm upgrade --install kfo "$CHART_URL" -f <(printf '%s' "$values")
```

Under the hood this creates a named pipe and passes a file descriptor such as `/dev/fd/123` to the helm install command. This feature is not available in some shells, such as dash (`/bin/sh` in Debian and Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Error: failed to parse /dev/fd/63: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected '-' indicator.  I'm getting this error when executing the helm chart.